# My landscape page is not A4

Tags: landscape

I am using the following code:

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
...
\begin{landscape}
...
\end{landscape}
```

Problem is that my landscape page is not A4. It is much more like a square.

Comment: Welcome! We need code we can compile to reproduce the problem. The code you've posted has nothing to do with the page dimensions. By default, your document will not use A4. But that is equally true of all pages - not just those in landscape orientation.

Comment: Are you sure **any** of your pages are A4?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}

This is what you want? 

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! I've just faced the same problem like topicstarter.
   `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} \usepackage{pdflscape} \begin{document} \begin{landscape} This is what you want? \end{landscape} No, it isn't. \end{document}`


Produces 2 pages with different dimentions. Do you have any ideas?