# Landscape page has different dimensions than portrait

Tags: geometry, landscape, pdflscape

My question is duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369750/my-landscape-page-is-not-a4). How to produce landscape page the same size like a portrait one?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        This is what you want?  
    \end{landscape} 
    No, it isn't.
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

Usage of `lscape` instead of `pdflscape` produces correct page size, but it is not rotated inside pdf document. How to do the trick?

Comment: They look the same size to me.

Comment: The package `pdflscape` rotate page in pdf viewer (on screen), meanwhile `lscape` not. Printed are both oriented equal and of course have equal page layout (which is equal to rotated `portrait` layout).

Comment: For sure are equal, if you not change landscape layout. To confirm this, try to measure their size presented on the screen. My measurements show, that are equal.

Comment: No, I mean really that if I measure your screenshot on screen with a plastic ruler they both are roughly `110mm x 78mm`.

Comment: Are you by any chance try to get a landscape page with the same *ratio* as an A4 paper but with the same *horizontal*  size? So basically an horizontal A5 page?

Comment: You are right, I don't know why they seemed to be different sizes for me=\